# Prove that the intersection have infinite elements

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I want to prove this theorem, and I made a proof but I want to know your opinion...

Theorem: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $A\neq \emptyset$, and $S=sup (A)$. Prove that if $S\notin A$, then $\forall \delta>0$ the set $A \cap (S-\delta,S)$ have infinite elements.

My proof:

First I'm going to prove that the intersection $A \cap (S-\delta,S) \neq \emptyset$, let's proceed by contradiction... Suppose that $A \cap (S-\delta,S) = \emptyset$ then there exists an $\alpha \in (S-\delta,S)$ s.t $\alpha \notin A$, then it satisfies that $a<\alpha<S, \forall a \in A$, this is a CONTRADICTION, because $S$ is the smallest upper bound (by the fact is the sup) and I found a smaller upper bound... Then the intersection is non empty...

Now I'm going to prove that $A \cap (S-\delta,S)$ have infinite elements proceeding by contradiction... Let's suppose that the intersection have a finite amount of elements, let's say $n$, all this elements are going to be labeled with $a_i$ with $i=1,...,n$ ordered from the smallest to the biggest one like: $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$, then it's clear that $a \leq a_n<S$ for all $a\in A$, this means that $a_n$ is the smallest upper bound of A, then $a_n$ is the $sup(A)$, and $a_n \in A$, this is a CONTRADICTION to the fact that $S$ is the $sup(A)$ and that $S \notin A$, then we get what we were looking for.

This is my proof... What's your opinion?

Comment: My opinion: it's good! I have no real criticisms to hand back. As an optional suggestion, perhaps you might want to expand on why "it's clear that $a \le a_n < S$ for all $a \in A$"? You could argue that either $a \le S - \delta$ or $a > S - \delta$. In the former case, then $a \le S - \delta < a_n$, and in the latter case, $a \le a_n$ because $a_n$ was assumed to be greatest in $(S - \delta, S) \cap A$. But, even without that clarification, I think the proof is fine.

Comment: Awesome suggestion @TheoBendit! Thank you

Comment: The proof is fine as is.  But since some members dislike proof by contradiction, here it is recast to avoid that:  Since $\sup A \in' A$, $A$ has no maximum element, so, since any maximum element of $A' = A \cap (S - \delta, S)$ is a maximum element of $A$, $A'$ has no maximum element, so, since $A'$ is non-empty, it's infinite.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need contradiction.  Suppose that $A$ is novoid and $\sup(A)\not \in A$.  Let $x_0 < \sup(S)$.  Then there is some $x_1\in A$ with $x < x_1 < \sup(A).$. Assume we have chose $x_1 < x_2 \cdots x_n < \sup(A)$.  Since $x_n < \sup(S)$ there is an $x_{n+1}\in S$ so that $x_{n+1} < \sup(A)$.  By induction we have an increasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\in S$, $n\ge 1$.

Comment: The original proof has the merit (if you consider it a merit) of not relying on the axiom of choice.

Comment: I am an axiom of choice kind of guy. And b'sides, this really is just relying on induction (and the existence of infinite sets).

Comment: You're right, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is pretty good, but you should edit more carefully. Language is very important in proofs, and there are a few points where your word choice/sentence structure/grammar confuses what you’re trying to say.

I see a couple things in particular that seem like bad habits you have and could be easily changed:

1. It’s hard to follow proofs with long run on sentences.
2. You shouldn’t use ellipses when they have no mathematical meaning.